# A query regarding abstract class in java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am writing a program where there are quite a lot number of methods in a particular class, so I decided to write an abstract class to help in keeping track of the methods.

Now, consider this: I have declared a method as abstract in the abstract class, and in the other class (which extends the abstract class), I want to override this method, but with access privilege reduced to private. Here, the compiler is giving a problem. It says that an attempt to assign weaker access privileges is being met with, which cannot be allowed. If I try to declare the method in the abstract class as protected (I have also changed the private ones to protected in the sub-class), it says that modifiers abstract and protected cannot be used together.

So, what can I do? Do I have to make the methods package access or public in both classes? If so, is there no way that I can declare these methods private?

Please note that I'm asking only for **abstract classes**, and not all classes in general.

Comment: How does having an abstract class help in "keeping track of the methods"?

Comment: You absolutely can have a `protected abstract` method.

Comment: Btw, this looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should probably elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ScottHunter Why not? Say, you have 12 methods in a particular class. Declaring an abstract class helps in seeing all the method definitions in one place and also helps in keeping track of their signatures and return types.

Comment: @bclarkreston not quite. I'm asking specifically about **abstract classes**.

Comment: lol @WrichikBasu use an IDE to explore and navigate all the class methods, no ?

Comment: Couldn't understand what you said. I'm working on BlueJ IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean it can not be `protected abstract` - *of course it can*.

And the thing that you want to do is basically prohibited by the compiler and the language itself in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: there's nothing you can do to reduce the visibility of a method declared in a parent class.

If you can restate what you're trying to accomplish by "keeping track of the methods" in an abstract parent class, you might get a different solution.